# Switch views, live bytes keep going up

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I guess this is a very common question to all of us. I have been doing hours of studying, but maybe because I am too junior, I still have no clue how to solve it. I am hoping someone could help.

Here is the scenario:

1. I have 3 View controllers on storyboard (none of them are back with code at this moment)
2. the 1st one (main one) has 7 `UIbuttons`, 4 `UIlabels`, and 3 `UIImages`, none of them are connected to the h file yet.
3. I use one of the buttons to connect to the next view (modal), and create one button on the 2nd view to connect to the 3rd one, and finally a button on view 3 to connect back to the Main view.

Seems very simple. However, when I run it on the instruments/allocation, I see there is a big jump on the live bytes (round 1MB) each time when I come back from view 3 to the main view.
(Recap: there is no code in "H" or "M" so far). Then, I tried to delete some of the buttons and labels, and redo the allocations. I see the live bytes still increase, but with smaller amount... clearly there is a unbounded memory growth issue (I guess).

So here is my question: how could we solve this? and how come they will allocate that much resource to the buttons, labels and images even they have nothing attached on it?

Many thanks!!

PS. no leak found on the report, and they are growing at the constant amount...

I tried this on the button for the Main view to go to view 2, but when I come back again it just can go back to the main on view3...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:Nil];

UIViewController *go2= [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];

[self presentViewController:go2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never "go back" to a previous controller using a segue (unless you use an unwind segue) because segues always create new view controllers. So, you're not really going back to the main view, you're creating a new instance of it. As you go through this cycle, you're adding more and more view controllers, and none of them ever gets deallocated. To correct this, you should either use an unwind segue to go back to the main view, or go back in code by using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Comment: Thx Rdelmar! is that meant using something like UIViewController *goback= [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main_one"];


            [self presentViewController:goback animated:YES completion:nil];
also will create a new VC?

Comment: I tried to use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: but the whole thing just paused and cannot go anywhere =.=

Comment: @Summerhei, yes, that creates a new instance.

Comment: @Summerhei, you should post your code to show what you've tried.

Comment: Master Rdelmar, I posted some code I've tried below the question. could you please give me some advice?

Comment: @Summerhei, you need to put your code in context, I can't understand what you've done where -- edit your post to show what code you have in each controller, and what results you're getting. Copy and paste the actual code, don't type it in.

Comment: Master Rdelmar, thank you very much! I follow you instruction to use unwind segue, and it works! much appreciated!!!!